# PHP sending email from client to server

Tags: php

This is send_email.php, I try this to receive feedback from my client, but when I try this code, I can't receive any comment or email.. what should I do to work this code snippet.

```
   <h2>Feedback Form</h2>
   <?php
   // display form if user has not clicked submit
   if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
  <?php 
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {

  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"]))  
    {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    $header = "From: $from\n";

mail("johnpatrickmderi@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$header);
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
    }
  }
?>
```

thank you

Comment: This is probably a problem with your server configuration, you should check your logs and/or turn on errors. It will probably say it can't connect to your mail (smpt) server or that none is configured.

Comment: have you tried debugging for any errors and check if the mails are not in `junk` folder....??

Comment: If you put your `echo "thank you";` _before_ the `mail` method, does your script output it?

Comment: `Mime-Version` and `Content-Type` should be defined at least. I would recommend you to use a framework for sending mails like phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer or swiftmailer http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: i tried to upload this in a free web hosting and it works but when i just run this code it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Emails function DOES NOT automatically work on local environment.
`mail` requires a configured Email Server which usually comes with any Server provider but is a bit tricky to implement on your own PC.

see here for alternative options: [link](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/)

or just debug on the server.

Comment: yes, it works but only if you have mail server. otherwise it does nothing, not even errors.